# dygraphs: using fillGraph with a custom plotter (barChart)

Tags: dygraphs

I am using dygraphs in the following example to display 3 Series of data 'Y1', 'Y2' and 'Y3'. My plan is to display 'Y1' as a bartChart and 'Y2' & 'Y3' as a filled Line.
For 'Y1' i used a custom plotter function **barChartPlotter()**.
For 'Y2' and 'Y3' i simply used the default **fillGraph** option. Here my Code:

```js
function darkenColor(colorStr) {
    // Defined in dygraph-utils.js
    var color = Dygraph.toRGB_(colorStr);
    color.r = Math.floor((255 + color.r) / 2);
    color.g = Math.floor((255 + color.g) / 2);
    color.b = Math.floor((255 + color.b) / 2);
    return 'rgba(' + color.r + ',' + color.g + ',' + color.b + ',0.5)';
}
function barChartPlotter(e) {
     var ctx = e.drawingContext;
        var points = e.points;
        var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0);

        ctx.fillStyle = darkenColor(e.color);

        // Find the minimum separation between x-values.
        // This determines the bar width.
        var min_sep = Infinity;
        for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
          var sep = points[i].canvasx - points[i - 1].canvasx;
          if (sep < min_sep) min_sep = sep;
        }
        var bar_width = Math.floor(2.0 / 3 * min_sep);

        // Do the actual plotting.
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
          var p = points[i];
          var center_x = p.canvasx;

          ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
              bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);

          ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
              bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
        }
}

g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
                 "X,Y1,Y2,Y3\n" +
                 "0,25,0,30\n" +
                 "1,20,10,27\n" +
                 "2,17,17,30\n" +
                 "3,16,23,28\n" +
                 "4,14,27,30\n" +
                 "5,13,30,29\n" +
                 "6,12,32,30\n" +
                 "7,11,33,30\n",
                 {
        "Y1": {
                         plotter: barChartPlotter
                     },
        "Y2": {
                     fillGraph: true
                    },
                    "Y3": {
                     fillGraph: true
                    }, 
                     title: 'Test'
                 });
```

```html
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-dev.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

As you can see in the snippet the fillGraph option is not working for 'Y2' and 'Y3'. But i noticed when i change the order of the Serie (make 'Y2' use the custom plotter instead of 'Y1'), **it worked**. See snippet below:

```js
function darkenColor(colorStr) {
    // Defined in dygraph-utils.js
    var color = Dygraph.toRGB_(colorStr);
    color.r = Math.floor((255 + color.r) / 2);
    color.g = Math.floor((255 + color.g) / 2);
    color.b = Math.floor((255 + color.b) / 2);
    return 'rgba(' + color.r + ',' + color.g + ',' + color.b + ',0.5)';
}
function barChartPlotter(e) {
     var ctx = e.drawingContext;
        var points = e.points;
        var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0);

        ctx.fillStyle = darkenColor(e.color);

        // Find the minimum separation between x-values.
        // This determines the bar width.
        var min_sep = Infinity;
        for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
          var sep = points[i].canvasx - points[i - 1].canvasx;
          if (sep < min_sep) min_sep = sep;
        }
        var bar_width = Math.floor(2.0 / 3 * min_sep);

        // Do the actual plotting.
        for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
          var p = points[i];
          var center_x = p.canvasx;

          ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
              bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);

          ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy,
              bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
        }
}

g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
                "X,Y1,Y2,Y3\n" +
                "0,25,0,30\n" +
                "1,20,10,27\n" +
                "2,17,17,30\n" +
                "3,16,23,28\n" +
                "4,14,27,30\n" +
                "5,13,30,29\n" +
                "6,12,32,30\n" +
                "7,11,33,30\n",
                {
    "Y1": {
        fillGraph: true
    },
    "Y2": {
        plotter: barChartPlotter
    },
    "Y3": {
        fillGraph: true
    }, 
    title: 'Test'
});
```

```html
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-dev.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

So i guess my question is: why is the **fillGraph** option not working for 'Y2' and 'Y3', when the **first** serie 'Y1' is using a custom plotter function? But it works fine when **Not** the first serie is usong a custom Plotter.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're running into [this issue](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/436).

Comment: @danvk : I dont know if this will help, but here it is anyway: I noticed that the Bug actually occurs when the first VISIBLE serie uses a custom plotter. So in the second Snippet (see above), if 'Y1' was invisible, 'Y2' would be the first visible serie. That would make fillGraph for 'Y3' not working.